# How to run dune build @doc with arguments

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune, ocamldoc

I have an ocaml project using Dune. I want to generate documentation using Odoc. Currently, running `dune build @doc` works, but I want to pass in the `-short-functors` option to Odoc. How do I pass options to Odoc through Dune?